# Unfindable MySQL error

Tags: mysql

I'm writing some PHP code to insert a value into my MySQL database:

```
INSERT INTO users_validate (uid, key) VALUES ('11', '4866ce5568850eb5f8daad79a8822d26')
```

Could anybody tell me what's wrong with this?

Edit: The error message is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES ('11', '4866ce5568850eb5f8daad79a8822d26')' at line 1
```

Comment: I've added it to my question!

Comment: Ah that stupid "*something went wrong*" message MySQL uses for nearly everything. That really is a pita.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to escape your column name `key`:

```
INSERT INTO users_validate (uid, `key`) VALUES ('11', '4866ce5568850eb5f8daad79a8822d26')
```

`KEY` is a reserved word in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html